# Multiple join on same table

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, primary-key, multiple-join-rows

My Schema is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ); 

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reseller_did` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phone` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `superadmin_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reseller_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`superadmin_id`) REFERENCES account(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`reseller_id`) REFERENCES account(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES account(`id`)
)
```

I want to find the phone with their superadmin, reseller, admin name. The problem is that I cant join multiple times on the same id. The query I have tried

```
select phone,superadmin_id,reseller_id, admin_id, name from reseller_did join 
account on account.id=reseller_did.admin_id
```

The above query display the admin name by joining on admin_id but how to get superadmin name and reseller name of the same phone?

**EDIT:**   Sample Input

**account table**

```
id     name

3      SuperAdmin1
9      Reseller1
10     Admin1
```

**reseller_did**

```
id  phone        superadmin_id   reseller_id   admin_id

1   9090909090   3                 9             10
```

**Sample output**

```
phone        superadmin    reseller    admin

9090909090   SuperAdmin1  Reseller1   Admin1
```

Comment: Please post some sample input and your expected output based on that.

Comment: @1000111 my mistake , updated the question

Comment: Similar to post [Get multiple values from another table by different relations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674462/get-multiple-values-from-another-table-by-different-relations/37674633#37674633)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;)

```
select r.phone, a.name as admin, re.name reseller, s.name as superadmin
from reseller_did r
join account a on a.id = r.admin_id
join account s on s.id = r.superadmin_id
join account re on re.id = r.reseller_id
```

[SqlFiddle Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0baad2/1/0)

Or

```
SELECT r.phone,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id = r.admin_id THEN a.name END) as admin,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id = r.reseller_id THEN a.name END) as reseller,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id = r.superadmin_id THEN a.name END) as superadmin
FROM reseller_did r
INNER JOIN account a 
ON a.id IN (r.admin_id, r.superadmin_id, r.reseller_id)
GROUP BY r.phone
```

This sql should thank to [@sagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5353753/sagi) in this question [Get multiple values from another table by different relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674462/get-multiple-values-from-another-table-by-different-relations/37674633#37674633).

[SqlFiddle Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0baad2/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```
select 
    rd.phone as Phone ,
    a.name as Superadmin,
    a1.name as Reseller,
    account.name as Admin
from
    reseller_did rd
        join
    account ON account.id = rd.admin_id
        join
    account a ON a.id = rd.superadmin_id
        join
    account a1 ON a1.id = rd.reseller_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make three aliases of `account` table and INNER JOIN these with `reseller_did` table

```
SELECT 
R.id,
R.phone,
A1.name AS superadmin,
A2.name AS reseller,
A3.name AS admin
FROM reseller_did R
INNER JOIN account A1 ON R.superadmin_id = A1.id 
INNER JOIN account A2 ON R.reseller_id = A2.id
INNER JOIN account A3 ON R.admin_id = A3.id ;
```

## [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO 1**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da99bf/1/0)

**Alternative way:**

You can use the following query to get the same result if you don't want to adopt INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT 
R.phone,
(SELECT name FROM account WHERE id = R.superadmin_id) AS SuperAdmin,
(SELECT name FROM account WHERE id = R.reseller_id) AS Reseller,
(SELECT name FROM account WHERE id = R.admin_id) AS Admin
FROM reseller_did R;
```

## [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO 2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da99bf/2/0)

**Caution:** You are storing phone number in `INT` datatype. You shouldn't use `INT` for storing phone number. Instead you should use `VARCHAR`.